# Overlap and add tensor in pytorch using nn.fold

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have the following problem, I have tensor with shape `(1,16198)`, first i would like to dive it into chunks so I used unfold like:

```
my_tensor.unfold(-1, 178, 89) -> tensor with shape (1, 182, 178)
```

which means 182 overlapping chunks of size `178`, that's perfect.

But now I would like to undo the operation adding the overlapping chunks and get back a `(1,16198)` tensor. I believe that the fold method would do that, but I've burned through several hours trying to understand how it works to no progress at all and I cant seem to find a good explanation source for how to use it and I am afraid the official documentation is way to complex for my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work last night, i had to transpose to the (1, 182, 178) tensor to (1, 178, 182) then I used

```
nn.Fold(my_tensor, (1, 16198), kernel_size=(1,178), stride=(1,89))
```

and i get
back my tensor with overlapping sections added, thus completing the overlap and add algorithm, still not sure how nn.Fold works.